# Elixir Arc - how to access to uploaded file

Tags: elixir

I use `Arc` to deal with uploading images. I want to upload to local storage for now.

this is my `uploader.ex`:

```
defmodule OkBackend.Uploader do
  use Arc.Definition
  def __storage, do: Arc.Storage.Local
  def asset_host, do: "http://localhost:4000"

  @versions [:original]

  def validate({file, _}) do
    ~w(.jpg .jpeg .gif .png) |> Enum.member?(Path.extname(file.file_name))
  end

  def filename(version, {file, scope}) do
      file_name = Path.basename(file.file_name, Path.extname(file.file_name))
    "#{scope}_#{file_name}"
  end

  def storage_dir(version, {file, scope}) do
    [user_id| _] = String.split(scope, "_", trim: true)
    "uploads/#{user_id}"
  end

  end
```

And in my controller:

```
  def upload(conn, params) do
    random_number = random_n_char_number_string(8)
    scope = params["user_id"] <> "_" <> random_number
    with { :ok, fname } <- Uploader.store({ params["image"], scope }) do
        render(conn, "upload.json", params: %{"status" => :success, "filename" => filename})
    end
  end
```

Example, if I have `user_id` is 1, and upload an image call `abc.png`, it will concat `params["user_id"]` and `random_number`("1_234765") into `scope` then save into folder `uploads/1/` with the file name `1_234765_abc.png`.

the problem is I when I try to access it via browser with:

```
HTTP://localhost:4000/uploads/1/1_234765_abc.png
```

I will get:

> no route found for GET /uploads/1/1_234765_abc.png
> (OkBackendWeb.Router)

I tried `Uploader.url/2`:

```
 IO.inspect(Uploader.url({filename, params["user_id"]}))
```

I will get:

> "/uploads/1/1_1_234765_abc.png"

notice the filename `1_1_468...`, an extra `1_` is concat into the filename, which I have no idea how that happen.

Honestly, I really don't understand how `Uploader.url/2` works.

Anything missing in my settings? How can I resolve this?

Comment: It looks like that code is governed by https://github.com/stavro/arc/blob/master/lib/arc/actions/url.ex so you should be able to override the url/3 function by defining it in your module.
It would be helpful if the package published some docs...